# Is there a risk that iCloud Private Relay interferes negatively with VPN service (for privacy)?

Tags: macos, icloud, vpn, privacy, email

iCloud Private Relay is currently in beta, and available for Macs with MacOS Monterey.

I sometimes use a VPN service for privacy purposes. Private Relay looks interesting as a "basic privacy protection" whenever I am not using the VPN.

However, I am concerned that activating Private Relay in some way may negatively interfere with the VPN, i.e. open it to privacy risks like disclosing my information or identity to some party.

I understand that there is "always" a risk that something bad can happen – but to put it more succinctly: do you think there is any reason for concern?

---

*NB 1:* For the record, I am using a VPN service via the OpenVPN protocol, with the VPN app Viscosity for MacOS.

*NB 2:* From what I've read on some random small tech blogs, Private Relay should ignore VPN traffic. Indeed, when I have Private Relay activated and the VPN on, if I go to a "What is my IP" site, I will see the VPN IP. But I think it's best to hear some different technical views around this, and get a canonical answer on Ask Different.

Comment: I've found that using Private Relay with my OpenVPN provider causes my internet speed to drop by 50-60%.  I understand why which is why I don't use PR.  I don't see how it could cause a privacy problem, though.